# Как сделать пункт меню не кликабельным, если он содержит подпункты?

Tags: css, wordpress

Сайт сделан на *WordPress*.
Один из пунктов меню имеет подпункты:

```
меню :
1) Салаты
2) Горячее
...
```

Если нажать на `меню :` - просто выведет все имеющиеся блюда.

Я попробовал :

```
pointer-events: none;
cursor: default;
```

Но тогда остальные подпункты выводиться не будут. Можно как-то по-другому сделать?

Comment: сделать его не ссылкой, а параграфом <p>

Answer (score 1):

Используйте

```
href="javascript: void(0)"
```

или просто запишите  `javascript: void(0)` в окошко URL при редактировании меню.

Answer (score 0):

Создать в меню произвольную ссылку с адресом `#`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Но тогда ведь при нажатии на кнопку(перед этим чуток спустимся вниз) - нас бросит просто наверх. Вроде подходит, но не корректно выходит)

Comment: С чего бы оно куда-то перемещалось? Нет конечно. Ну разве что для этого будет специально написан какой-то  яваскрипт.